# Error instantiating path.to.Action Implementing class in install4j while importing a custom action

Tags: java, install4j

I have created a custom action in order to preserve some settings during the upgrade process, however when I try to configure my installer to use that action I get the error:

Error instantiating "path.to.Action:" Implementing class.

The action follows the same basic structure of some of the other custom actions used in the installer (extends AbstractInstallAction, and overrides the install method).

Is there some specific thing that needs to be done to my class in order for it to function correctly, or is the problem in the installer itself?

Comment: Where exactly do you get that exception, when you try to add the action in the install4j IDE or when you run the installer?

Comment: @IngoKegel when i tried to add the action (in the ide before running the installer)

Comment: Then there are dependencies in the class file that have not been added on the Installer->Custom code & Resources step.

Comment: Sorry for the long timespan to reply (it got a bit hectic at work). I have identified the dependency that needs to be filled (Guava), but when I add the guava jar file to Custom Code & Resources I get the same result. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: That should work if you have added the JAR file with the action on that Custom code & Resources tab (and not as an extension). I cannot give any more advice without further information. Try instantiating the action in a test project in your IDE.